# Custom Sorting in Meteor

Tags: mongodb, sorting, session, meteor, ranking

I'm basically trying to create my own ranking system and wanting to display users based off the highest ranked user to the lowest ranked user.  For example lets say I have a user collection:

```
{_id: "CwqaMwgyRNa3G99HD", createdAd: Fri Oct 30, profile: {...}},
{_id: "AcqaMwgyRNa3G99HD", createdAd: Fri Oct 30, profile: {...}},
{_id: "hrqaMwgyRNa3G99HD", createdAd: Fri Oct 30, profile: {...}},
{_id: "DsfaMwgyRNa3G99HD", createdAd: Fri Oct 30, profile: {...}},
{_id: "fdsqaMwgyRNa3G99HD", createdAd: Fri Oct 30, profile: {...}}
```

I want to be able to write a function and rank the above users and ideally go through those users and add a ranking property (on the client side) based on a function.  For example:

```
if(Meteor.user.profile.name == "Bob"){
  // Add 5 to the rank property
}else if(Meteor.user.profile.job == "Business Man"){
  // Add 5 more to the rank property    
}

// Now users have rank property added to them based on the function above
{_id: "CwqaMwgyRNa3G99HD",rank: 5, createdAd: Fri Oct 30, profile: {...}},
{_id: "AcqaMwgyRNa3G99HD", rank: 10, createdAd: Fri Oct 30, profile: {...}},
{_id: "hrqaMwgyRNa3G99HD", rank: 5, createdAd: Fri Oct 30, profile: {...}},
{_id: "DsfaMwgyRNa3G99HD", createdAd: Fri Oct 30, profile: {...}},
{_id: "fdsqaMwgyRNa3G99HD", createdAd: Fri Oct 30, profile: {...}}
```

I lastly then want to display the users on the client side with the highest rank first.  So ideally the ID with a rank of 10 would show then the two with a rank of 5 and then the rest.  Any idea of how to do this? I would ideally like this to be done on the client side because I just need this to be shown on the client and not stored in mongo.  Would I used a session for this? If so, I'm not quite sure how to do a session like that.  Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 1):

You could try using the collection.forEach method to compute the rankings and the _.sortBy to sort the resulting docs.

So for example you could define a template helper like so:

```
Template.rankings.helpers({
  user: function() { 
    var rankings = [];
    var sorted;

    Meteor.users.find().forEach(function(user, index) {
      var rank = 0;
      if(user.profile.name == "Bob"){
        rank = rank + 5;
      }
       if(user.profile.job == "Business Man"){
        // Add 5 more to the rank property    
        rank = rank + 5
      } 
      user.rank = rank;
      rankings.push(user); 
    }):

    sorted = _.sortBy(rankings, rank);
    return sorted;

   }
});
```

And then iterate over the sorted list in your template like so:

```
<template name="rankings">
  {{#each user}} 
    {{rank}}, {{profile.name}}, {{profile.job}}
  {{/each}}
</template>
```